# Exporting json file of database looks different from web interface

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am using Firebase to store my data but for some reason the json file and web interface is different. Why is the JSON file in an array? How do I fix this? Thanks!

Web interface:

[image]

Json File:

```
  {
  "data" : [ {
    "age" : "35",
    "agratio" : "0.9",
    "alb" : "3.3",
    "alkphos" : "187",
    "db" : "0.1",
    "diagonsis" : "yes",
    "gender" : "1",
    "sgot" : "18",
    "sgpt" : "16",
    "tb" : "0.7",
    "tp" : "6.8"
  }, {
    "age" : "35",
    "agratio" : "0.9",
    "alb" : "3.3",
    "alkphos" : "187",
    "db" : "0.1",
    "diagonsis" : "no",
    "gender" : "1",
    "sgot" : "18",
    "sgpt" : "16",
    "tb" : "0.7",
    "tp" : "6.8"
  }, {
    "age" : "35"
  }, {
    "age" : "20"
  } ],
  "users" : {
    "234234adfsdsf" : {
      "username" : "hey"
    },
    "BbZZCTIIcJdvCCU9og905kKVvo53" : {
      "email" : "andyjiang55@yahoo.com",
      "username" : "andyjiang"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database internally doesn't store array. It instead stores array-like structure as regular JavaScript objects/associative arrays, with the numeric sequential indexes as keys, like you see in the console.

The Firebase SDKs and REST API (which the export JSON feature uses under the hood) have logic built in to convert array-like JSON structures back to actual arrays when they see them. So that's why the exported JSON contains an array, while the console shows the actual structure that the database stores under the hood.

Also see:

- the blog post [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thank you @Frank , I was searching for a long time!